# Как решить проблему?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать возможность перемещать блок с помощью кнопок, но кнопки вниз-вверх почему-то не работают, хотя все остальные отрабатывают верно, в чем может быть проблема? Весь код прикрепил ниже

```js
var topPos = 0;
var leftPos = 0;
var top = document.getElementById("top");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
var moveBlock = document.getElementById("moveBlock");


function moveTop() {
  topPos -= 15;
  moveBlock.style.top = topPos + "px";
}

function moveLeft() {
  topPos += 15;
  leftPos -= 15;
  moveBlock.style.left = leftPos + "px";
}

function moveBottom() {
  topPos += 15;
  moveBlock.style.top = topPos + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  leftPos += 15;
  topPos += 15;
  moveBlock.style.left = leftPos + "px";
}

left.onclick = moveLeft;
right.onclick = moveRight;
bottom.onclick = moveBottom;
top.onclick = moveTop;
```

```css
#top,
#bottom,
#right,
#left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.mainBlock {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#moveBlock {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <input id="top" type="button" value="TOP">
  <input id="bottom" type="button" value="BOTTOM">
  <input id="left" type="button" value="LEFT">
  <input id="right" type="button" value="RIGHT">

  <div class="mainBlock">
    <div id="moveBlock"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конфликт между названиями глобальных переменных и свойствами `window`.

```js
var topPos = 0;
var leftPos = 0;
var moveBlock = document.getElementById("moveBlock");


function moveTop() {
  topPos -= 15;
  moveBlock.style.top = topPos + "px";

  console.log(leftPos, topPos, moveBlock.style.left, moveBlock.style.top);
}

function moveLeft() {
  leftPos -= 15;
  moveBlock.style.left = leftPos + "px";

  console.log(leftPos, topPos, moveBlock.style.left, moveBlock.style.top);
}

function moveBottom() {
  topPos += 15;
  moveBlock.style.top = topPos + "px";

  console.log(leftPos, topPos, moveBlock.style.left, moveBlock.style.top);
}

function moveRight() {
  leftPos += 15;
  moveBlock.style.left = leftPos + "px";

  console.log(leftPos, topPos, moveBlock.style.left, moveBlock.style.top);
}

document.getElementById("top").onclick = moveTop;
document.getElementById("bottom").onclick = moveBottom;
document.getElementById("left").onclick = moveLeft;
document.getElementById("right").onclick = moveRight;
```

```css
#top,
#bottom,
#right,
#left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

.mainBlock {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#moveBlock {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id="top" type="button" value="TOP">
<input id="bottom" type="button" value="BOTTOM">
<input id="left" type="button" value="LEFT">
<input id="right" type="button" value="RIGHT">

<div class="mainBlock">
  <div id="moveBlock"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, понял, тоесть проблема заключается в совпадении названий переменных со свойствами window, запомню :)